# Community Builder: Hide/Replace navigation bar in Partner Central template

Tags: community, navigation, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page

I am using the Partner Central template in lightning community and want to customize the navigation bar such that it displays a different set of items based on the user. The criteria however, is a quite complicated and cannot be done through the personalize menu. So, I want to replace the default navigation menu with a custom component. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Well, one solution is to put a custom component in the header and put a VF Page in the footer that uses the window.parent.document.queryselector in JS to delete the original navigation bar. It's a bit to hacky to use outside of a trailhead playground though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish that using a [custom theme layout](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:themeLayout/documentation) + [forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:navigationMenuBase/documentation)